# Testing whether a .NET application is running with full trust

Tags: .net, security, full-trust

How do you test from .NET whether an application is running with full trust?

My application is running in .NET 2.0 and needs to work with that framework.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d005ted.aspx

Comment: Do you simply want to test whether the application is running under full trust, or do you want to prevent it from running at all if it has a restricted permission grant?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is a blog [Finding out the current trust level in asp.net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/23/finding-out-the-current-trust-level-in-asp-net.aspx) which looks promising.  I pasted the code here in case the blog dies.

```
// Here is a sample code that returns the current trust level, assuming this
// code (or the calling code up the stack), is not loaded from GAC:

AspNetHostingPermissionLevel GetCurrentTrustLevel() {
  foreach (AspNetHostingPermissionLevel trustLevel in
    new AspNetHostingPermissionLevel [] {
      AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Unrestricted,
      AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.High,
      AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Medium,
      AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Low,
      AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal 
        }) {
    try {
        new AspNetHostingPermission(trustLevel).Demand();
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException ) {
        continue;
    }

    return trustLevel;
    }
  return AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.None;
}

// The result can be cached in a static field 
// for the duration of the app domain lifetime.
```